# noscript fails to display in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a section that is not displaying in IE 11 when javascript is disabled.

I have narrowed it down to the noscript tag. I found some online references to CSS not working, but I can't find any CSS referencing noscript in my code.

This is now the entire spark page.

```
<noscript>Javascript is disabled!</noscript>
Test
<script>alert('JS is on')</script>
```

Displays correctly in Chrome and FF, but IE 11 throws the alert. That makes it look like JS is NOT disabled.

But I added these two lines to another website

```
 <noscript>Javascript is disabled!</noscript>
 <script>alert('JS is on')</script>
```

That page shows "Javascript is disabled!" in another tab in the same browser, so I assume same settings. I have toggled the 'disable script setting' and restarted IE.

I don't know what to suspect/tear down next.

The page for the working site is .cshtml whereas this has .spark extension. Both compiled and deployed by VS.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you've disabled JavaScript? Try adding `<script>alert('JS is on')</script>` or something like that and see if you get an alert

Comment: In some browsers disabling Javascript rather works as "don't download/execute Javascript".

Comment: @Phil Now I'm confused. My other site shows the proper noscript "enable javascript" message . But on this page the alert pops up. I'll add the alert to the other page and see what I get.

Comment: @BWhite sounds like you haven't disabled JavaScript. See https://www.technipages.com/internet-explorer-enabledisable-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
 <div id="no-script"> Your Script Is Disabled </div>
```

and try to hide id with script

```
document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("no-script"))
```

after it

Comment: Except it doesn't handle all. This did better  <!--document.getElementById("no-script").remove()--> *This* works in all cases I've tried.
          var mydiv = document.getElementById('no-script');
          mydiv.parentNode.removeChild(mydiv);